# Run 2 aplications simultaneously with python and save csv files

Tags: python, csv, windows-11

I am trying to write a single python app that extracts data from an ICU monitor via ETH and grabs data from a HTTP endpoint and save the data input as csv files. They should be opend at the exact same time so that the data timestamp is the same.
The program that reads the ICU data is called VitalSignsCapture.

[VitalSignCapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0roWp.png)

As shown in the photo there are 6 in-app settings you have to make to run the program to your liking.

So far I wrote a code that opens both at the same time but there is no posibility to set the in-app options.

Could somebody pls help me. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could multiple processes.
one main which define the future time stamp at which both action will be performed, and which passes this timestamp via a queue to the second.
Then at the given time stamp both process execute their own tasks~

*seems like it's better to edit than to add another answer so I edit~*

You can make 2 functions (A & B), one for each of your two actions.

```
def A(*args, **kwargs):
   get ICU data and save it to whatever format you need
def B(*args, **kwargs):
   get HTTP request data and save it to whatever format you need
```

Then, you define when you want to call them  and use for instance threading.Timer to call them. Timer takes as input how long from call it should wait before running a specific function.
So you do your math to define how long you want to wait before calling both functions together. For instance, something like :

`waitTime = target_timeStamp - current_time`

and you call your functions

```
threading.Timer(waitTime, A).start()
threading.Timer(waitTime, B).start()
```

doc there for the details of Timer (at the bottom)
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

The thing is that the two thread will be "simultaneous" modulo your interpreter and machine. If you get limited and need the time between the two functions to be reduced, then you need to do something similar, but before you must call your Timer from 2 different processes.

And if that it not doing it for you, then I'd suggest to move to C/CPP if you really need to go as fast as the OS can do, but I am not sure it will be really relevant in your case, since anyway your http request will have some delay due to the ping.

Also you should save each data with its corresponding timestamp, so if you cannot match exactly the timings you want, you can also interpolate the values~

Hope this explanation helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. But how would you write the code that opens the VitalSignsCapture and simultaneously allows the input of settings. And how do I start the second programe at the same time? Is it posible to use a "if" statement?